# Extend div to bottom of page (only HTML and CSS)

Tags: html, css, position

Its a very simple problem but I can't seem to find a suitable solution online. I want to have a list of elements in natural flow with the last element extended to the bottom of the page. So if I have

```
<div id="top" style="height:50px;"></div>
<div id="bottom" style="background:lightgrey;"></div>
```

I need element `bottom` to extend from the bottom of `top` to the bottom of the page. Any solution that uses only html and css is welcome, and you can add container divs or anything, as long as I can get dynamic resizing of the `bottom` div

EDIT:
I don't want to hard-code any values for `bottom`, because I want `bottom` to adjust if `top` is resized

here's a fiddle for all your fiddling needs: http://jsfiddle.net/8QnLA/

Answer (score 70, accepted):

### Solution: #1: css tables:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
body {
  display: table;
  margin: 0;
}
#top, #bottom {
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  display: table-row;
}
#top {
  height: 50px;
}
#bottom {
  background: lightgrey;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
body {
  display: table;
  margin: 0;
}
#top, #bottom {
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  display: table-row;
}
#top {
  height: 50px;
}
#bottom {
  background: lightgrey;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="top" style="height:50px;"><span>A header</span></div>
<div id="bottom" style="background:lightgrey;"><span>The content area - extends to the bottom of the page</span></div>
```

[**Codepen #1 (little content)**](https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/QMgWqw)

**[Codepen #2 (lots of content)](https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/PKjoev)**

### Solution #2: Using calc and viewport units

```
#top {
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
}
#bottom {
  background: lightgrey;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 50px);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#top {
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
}
#bottom {
  background: lightgrey;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 50px);
}

Where `min-height: calc(100vh - 50px);` means:

'Let the height of the content div be **at least** 100% of the viewport height minus the 50px height of the header.'
```

```html
<div id="top" style="height:50px;"><span>A header</span></div>
<div id="bottom" style="background:lightgrey;"><span>The content area - extends to the bottom of the page</span></div>
```

**[Codepen #1 (little content)](https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/eERYLW)**

**[Codepen #2 (lots of content)](https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/aywbRE)**

### Solution #3 - Flexbox

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#top {
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
}
#bottom {
  background: lightgrey;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#top {
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
}
#bottom {
  background: lightgrey;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="top" style="height:50px;"><span>A header</span></div>
<div id="bottom" style="background:lightgrey;"><span>The content area - extends to the bottom of the page</span></div>
```

**[Codepen #1 - little content](https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/KvqKjN)**

**[Codepen #2 - lots of content](https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/MvoWMo)**

Comment: wow thanks for going above and beyond, but the table method was the best for me!

Comment: Solution 2 will only work if you have content that is visible - if anything extends past the fold - that's where the "#bottom" element will extend to and stop. So it would extend to the bottom of the page from what I understand.

Comment: Solution 2 doesnt work with safari since it doesnt support calculations involving the viewport-relative units vh and vw.

Comment: @user1230795 - thanks for pointing that out - I updated the post using the `min-height` property instead of the `height` property.

Comment: @ThomasMaier - I updated solution 2 and i just verified that it works in Safari. The problem was that I had used the 'height` property instead of the `min-height` property.

Comment: @Danield Oh, cool! But I did read also, that Safari doesn't support it. In addition to me trying to use it and cursing Safari. calc + viewport units is the master sword for a lot of responsive design realisation problems.

Answer (score 3):

Set the height of `html, body` to `100%`.  Then, you can set the last `<div>`'s height to `100%` and it will be as tall as the window.  Since you probably don't want scrolling, you can set `overflow: hidden` on the `html, body` as well.

http://jsfiddle.net/GKbzx/

Comment: @web-tiki it would only hide part of the content if the content extended past the bottom of the page.  If it did, a solution like this wouldn't be necessary in the first place

Comment: OP seems to need a solution that can adapt to several situations like  layout is used on several pages with different content and/or the content is supposed to be updated and/or content displayed on several size viewports. In all these situations content can exeed the bottom of page.

Comment: -1 Because OP writes that he needs element `bottom` to extend from the bottom of `top` to the bottom of the page; not *beyond* the page.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for react or vanilla JS.

```js
const useExpandToPageBottom = () => {
    const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
    useEffect(() => {
      if (!ref.current) return;
      const { y } = ref.current.getBoundingClientRect();
      ref.current.style.height = `${window.innerHeight - y}px`;
    });

    return { ref };
};
```

Use hook like so:

```js
const { ref } = useExpandToBottom()

<div ref={ref}>Div to expand</div>
```