# 100% Height without scrollbars (parent and nested childs with flexbox)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I like to 100% height without any scrollbars. In my example the browser seems to calculate the entire height. How the child get 100% height of parent element.

**html**

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="header"></div> //<- Here is the problem
<div class="content">
    <div class="element">
       <div class="element-child1"></div>
       <div class="element-child2"></div>
    </div>
<div/>
```

**css**

```
  html, body, .wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
  }

  .wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .wrapper > .header {
    flex: 0 0 40px;
    background-color: black;
  }

  .wrapper > .content {
    align-self: stretch;
    flex: 1;
    background: red;
  }

  .element {
     align-self: stretch;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     background-color: yellow;
  }

  .element-child1 {
     flex: 0 0 20px;
     background-color: blue;
  }

  .element-child2 {
     flex: 1;
     background-color: green;
  }
```

Example with scrollbars: http://jsfiddle.net/zyYPv/

Comment: take a look at my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/22934372/703717

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to make use of the `flex-grow` property:

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="element-child1"></div>
        <div class="element-child2"></div>
    <div/>
</div>
```

**Css**

```
html, body, .wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.wrapper > .header {
    flex: 0 0 40px;
    background-color: black;
}

.wrapper > .content {
    flex-grow: 1;    
    display: flex;
    background: red;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.element-child1 {
    flex: 0 0 20px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.element-child2 {
    flex-grow: 1;
    background-color: green;
}
```

[`flex-grow` example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/zyYPv/11/)

**Alternatives**

[`calc` example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/zyYPv/5/)

[`display:table` example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/zyYPv/4/)

Comment: I've already did this. Flexbox solution will be more nicely. Do not need any support. Just for my own. If there is no answer with flexbox you got the accept.

Answer (score 0):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zyYPv/3/)

CSS

```
  html, body, .wrapper {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding:0;
  }
  .wrapper > .header {
      height: 40px;
      background-color: black;
  }
  .content {
      position:absolute;
      top:40px;
      bottom:0;
      background: red;
      width:100%;
  }
  .element {
      height: 100%;
      background-color: yellow;
  }
  .element-child1 {
      height: 20px;
      background-color: blue;
  }
  .element-child2 {
      background-color: green;
      position:absolute;
      top:20px;
      bottom:0;
      width:100%;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks but that is not what i asking. I can not just remove the parent elements.

Comment: @MR.ABC - sorry it was unclear what you were asking, please see above for updated answer

Comment: Yeah it's difficult sometimes. Element-child2 is not 100% anymore. It do not fill the content.

Comment: @MR.ABC - still not clear what you mean, add `overflow-y:scroll` to `.element-child2`

Comment: I just need a 100% element. overflow-y:scroll will destroy the layout underneath.