# Last table row at the end of the page

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, printing, html-table

I want my table to look like this image:

[image: What I Want?]

My table looks like this image:

[image: What it is?]

So, how to do that?

**How my table is generated:**

```
<table id="chiru_inv" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered table-responsive">
   <tr>
    <td colspan="4" align="center">
      <h1>Company</br><span style="font-size: 75%;">Number</span></h1>
    </td>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <h3><span style="float: left;">Bill No.: 4</span></h3>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
      <h3><span style="float: right;">Date: </span></h3>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">
      <h3>Customer: </h3>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Sr.</th>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>Qty</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
  </tr>
    <?php
    $i = 0;
    $total = 0;
        while($rowc)
        {
            extract($rowc);
            $i++;

?>

    <tr>
      <td style="border-top:none !important; border-bottom:none !important;">
      <?php echo $i; ?>
      </td>
      <td style="border-top:none !important; border-bottom:none !important;">
      <?php
      $itm = $IRN;
      $stmti = $user_home->runQuery('SELECT * FROM item WHERE IRN = :iinv ');
    $stmti->bindParam(':iinv',$itm);
    $stmti->execute();
    $rowci = $stmti->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
      echo $rowci['Name']; 
      $srv = $SRN;
      $stmts = $user_home->runQuery('SELECT * FROM service WHERE SRN = :sinv ');
    $stmts->bindParam(':sinv',$srv);
    $stmts->execute();
    $rowcs = $stmts->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
      ?>
      &nbsp;(<?php echo $rowcs['Name']; ?>)
      </td>
      <td style="border-top:none !important; border-bottom:none !important;">
      <?php echo $Quantity; ?>
      </td>
      <td style="border-top:none !important; border-bottom:none !important;">
      <?php echo $Amnt; ?>
      </td>
    </tr>

            <?php
            $total = $total + $Amnt;
        $rowc=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }
        ?>

    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><strong><?php echo getIndianCurrency($total); ?>Only</strong></td>
      <td><strong>Total:</strong></td>
      <td><strong><?php echo $total; ?></strong></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

The **table** can have only **1** **row**, or **2** or it can have **4** **rows** also!

For all the **rows**, **table** should always be [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPoYF.jpg) only.

[image]

The **rows** of the **table** change according to the records in the **database**.

Comment: Would this help? http://jsfiddle.net/CBQCA/1/

Comment: Add `bottom-margin` to your `<tr>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extend div to bottom of page (only HTML and CSS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22934016/extend-div-to-bottom-of-page-only-html-and-css)

Comment: @SNTiwari to the last tr?

Comment: How did you make it look like the expected result;)

Comment: @Akintunde by adding `<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr` many times!

Comment: @Akintunde Any updates?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <table id="chiru_inv" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered table-responsive">
       <tr>
        <td colspan="4" align="center">
          <h1>Company</br><span style="font-size: 75%;">Number</span></h1>
        </td>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
          <h3><span style="float: left;">Bill No.: 4</span></h3>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
          <h3><span style="float: right;">Date: </span></h3>
        </td>
      </tr>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
          <h3>Customer: </h3>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Sr.</th>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Qty</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
      </tr>
        <?php
    $i = 0;
    $total = 0;
    $stmttr = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM invoice WHERE BRN = :inv"); // Your query
    $stmttr->bindParam(':inv',$irn);
$allRows = $stmttr->rowCount(); // Count Total rows available in result
$tri = 0; // initiate variable to check <tr> status
        while($rowc)
        {
            extract($rowc);
            $i++;

?>

    <tr  <?php if(++$tri==$allrows) { ?> style="padding-bottom: 100px;"<?php } ?>   >
          <td style="border-top:none !important; border-bottom:none !important;">
          <?php echo $i; ?>
          </td>
          <td style="border-top:none !important; border-bottom:none !important;">
          <?php
          $itm = $IRN;
          $stmti = $user_home->runQuery('SELECT * FROM item WHERE IRN = :iinv ');
        $stmti->bindParam(':iinv',$itm);
        $stmti->execute();
        $rowci = $stmti->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
          echo $rowci['Name']; 
          $srv = $SRN;
          $stmts = $user_home->runQuery('SELECT * FROM service WHERE SRN = :sinv ');
        $stmts->bindParam(':sinv',$srv);
        $stmts->execute();
        $rowcs = $stmts->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
          ?>
          &nbsp;(<?php echo $rowcs['Name']; ?>)
          </td>
          <td style="border-top:none !important; border-bottom:none !important;">
          <?php echo $Quantity; ?>
          </td>
          <td style="border-top:none !important; border-bottom:none !important;">
          <?php echo $Amnt; ?>
          </td>
        </tr>

                <?php
                $total = $total + $Amnt;
            $rowc=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            }
            ?>

        <tr>
          <td colspan="2"><strong><?php echo getIndianCurrency($total); ?>Only</strong></td>
          <td><strong>Total:</strong></td>
          <td><strong><?php echo $total; ?></strong></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
```

Comment: @BTC try to update with second last `<tr>` , see updated answer

Comment: As rows will be inserted as per `mysql database` I also don't know at which state which will be the **second last `<tr`>**

Comment: @BTC check code for row count for your query result

Comment: if `$i=0;` condition should be `if(++$i == $count) `

Comment: @BTC just remove extra `$tri++` from your code, & try to print and check all necessary variables before condition checking

Comment: Any Updates sir?

Comment: because of your `$tri` value check initial value & print to check for last row

Comment: So, what to change?